# R: Subsetting data of class "rating"

Tags: r, subset, rating

I have an object generated using the 'glicko' function from the 'PlayerRatings' package.

```
Glicko Ratings For 34 Players Playing 485 Games

       Player Rating Deviation Games  Win Draw Loss Lag
1      SC     2545      143.06    10    9    0    1  12
2      WLS    2502      107.22    17   15    0    2  66
3      CC     2486       72.66    56   48    0    8   5
4      R      2447       92.22    22   17    0    5  64...
```

The glicko output gives me an object of the class "rating" which I would like to subset into three while retaining the ratings that each were given but I am unable to subset an object of this type.

Any advice? Thanks.

Rachel

Comment: The table is probably stored somewhere in the object. Try looking at `str(yourobject)`, find the table and assign it to a separate variable. Then you should be able to subset as normal.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for your help and the fast response. Much appreciated.